# One to many relation data sending

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am unable to send lasted inserted autoincrement id value to another table
this is my code
i am getting error is Must declare the scalar variable "@userid".

```
int ID;

    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["samplefkConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sampdb values(@name,@phone);"+ "Select Scope_Identity()", cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", TextBox2.Text);



    cn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    cn.Close();
    TextBox1.Text = "";
    TextBox2.Text = "";
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into sampfk values(@emailid,@address,@userid)", cn);


    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox4.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ID);
    cn.Open();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cn.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
    TextBox3.Text = "";
    TextBox4.Text = "";
```

Comment: are you getting value in "ID" variable after insert in "sampdb" table?

Comment: yes I am getting value in ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do above in single step, you should use `using` more and try to nest query if possible. Opening TCP connection frequently has some acknowledgement overheads.

```
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["samplefkConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = @"INSERT INTO sampdb VALUES (@name,@phone);
                             INSERT INTO sampfk VALUES (SCOPE_IDENITTY(), @address, @emailid); ";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox4.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your problem.you have written

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into sampfk values (@userid, @address, @emailid)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", TextBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox4.Text)
```

but executing

```
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

you should add parameter in cmd2 not cmd like as

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ID);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox4.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line.

```
ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

If this doesn't return anything, then use a default value for ID, maybe 0.

Or add a default value in the declaration as `int id = 0;`

Comment: got an error Must declare the scalar variable "@emailid".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
{
  string sql1 = "insert into sampdb values(@name,@phone);"+ "Select Scope_Identity()";
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, cn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", TextBox2.Text);
    cn.Open();
    ID =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  //ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
  cn.Close();
  TextBox1.Text = "";
  TextBox2.Text = "";
  string sql2 = "insert into sampfk values (@userid, @address, @emailid)";
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2, cn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox4.Text);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  con.Dispose();
  con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I got it by update my code thank you for your answers